# How do I call scala functions in my external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scala

I have my scala function in a controller file and want to use it in an if-statement inside my external javascript file.

Here is my scala function:

```
def checkExistingEmail(email: String):Boolean = {
   val editorEmails = editorRepo.allWithEmail(email)
   val initatorEmails = initiatorRepo.allWithEmail(email)
   val emailCount = editorEmails.length + initatorEmails.length

   return (emailCount == 0)
}
```

I want to use it my if-condition in this javascript function:

```
$("#fbLoginButton").click(function() { 
    if(//HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO USE MY SCALA FUNCTION)
    FB.login(); 
    });
```

How do I call a scala function in my external javascript file? :)

Comment: wouldn't you be required to make an ajax call from the javascript?

Comment: I'm assuming this is scala running on a webserver somewhere? Are you using any particular framework? The answer is basically 'you need to expose that function through a webpage and call it', but if you gave more details people may be able to expand on that.

Comment: @Impredicative, youre correct that it is scala running on an webserver and I'm using play framework.

Comment: @GonçaloVieira, I'm a little familiar with ajax but what do you mean with 'make an ajax call'?

Comment: make a get or post request to the Controller, this one should handle all of the login functionality, it should return, to the javascript, whatever details you want that are returned to it

basically check how to make a GET or a POST handler for the Controller, afterwards check out on how to make an ajax GET/POST request, depending on what you chose to do

Comment: Thank you @GonçaloVieira, I've looked into what you proposed and your answer got me on the right track and eventually I got it to work as I wanted!